# Create sparse matrix with pandas and fill it with values from one column of .dat file at indexes [x,y] from other two columns of .dat file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a .dat file, that contains three columns - *userID*, *artistID* and *weight*.
Using Python, I read the data into pandas Dataframe with *data = pd.read_table('train.dat')*.

I want to create a sparse matrix (/2D array), that takes the values from the first two columns ('*userID*', '*artistID*') of *data* Dataframe as indexes and the third column as value ('*weight*').
Combinations of indexes, not given in the Dataframe, should be *NaN*.

I tried creating an empty numpy array and filling it, using a for loop, but it takes a lot of time (there are around 100k rows in train.dat).

```
import csv
import numpy as np

f = open("train.dat", "rt")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
next(reader)
data = [d for d in reader]
f.close()

data = np.array(data, dtype=float)
col = int(a[:,0].max()) + 1
row = int(a[:,1].max()) + 1

empty = np.empty((row, col))
empty[:] = np.nan

for d in data:
   empty[int(d[0]), int(d[1])] = d[2]
```

Also tried creating a coo_matrix and converting it to csr_matrix (so I could access data with indexes), but indexes reset.

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table('train.dat')
matrix = sps.coo_matrix((data.weight, (data.index.labels[0], data.index.labels[1])))
matrix = matrix.tocsr()
```

Data example:

```
userID    artistID  weight
    45           7      0.7114779874213837
   204         144      0.46399999999999997
    36         650      2.4232887490165225
   140         146      1.0146699266503667
   170          31      1.4124783362218372
   240         468      0.6529992406985573
```

Comment: [mcve] please, I understand data better than english.

Comment: It seems you are new to numpy and scipy. Read some introduction first to understand why loops are usually slow and how sparse matrices work (many different forms). After some time studying scipy.sparse you should be able to create your matrix. (sidenote: in these rating- / collaborative-filtering- / matrix-factorization-tasks i usually don't want to use sparse-matrices as implemented by scipy; but keep dense numpy arrays which feel more natural / direct in many algorithms)

Comment: Yes, I'm new to scipy, numpy and also Stack Overflow. :) @COLDSPEED I added some code examples. Sascha I'll definitely read some more documentation, but I couldn't find any good suggestions for my problem. So using a usual numpy array (like in the first code example) is better? What about time efficiency?

Comment: We don't know your problem, so it's hard to help. You only described that you need a sparse-matrix based on some pandas dataframe. I implemented some matrix-factorization algs in the past (not necessarily what you are doing) and there was never a reason to use sparse matrices (as supported by scipy; of course keeping 3 dense vectors as you have originally is a sparse-matrix too, in some form).

Comment: The code would help, but without the data, it doesn't help much :-(

Comment: I'm implementing a collaborative filtering algorithm, that calculates missing weights (rates) using item-item similarity (for a recommender system). After that I'll try to implement latent factor recommender system (matrix factorization). I don't know what is the best way to handle data as the program (with collaborative filtering) does a lot of comparing with for loops. The program is not yet optimized, but for optimization I firstly need the right data representation.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ totally forgot, sorry. Added an example.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "the indexes reset", but I would say that constructing this using ``sparse.coo_matrix`` is definitely the best approach available within numpy/scipy/pandas.

Comment: If the indexes in 'userID' column are from 0 to 10, and for example 8 and 9 are not in the train.dat, the .tocsr() method resets the indexes to 1 - 8 (because there are 8 unique indexes in column ''userID').
Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your data copied to file:

```
In [290]: data = pd.read_csv('stack48133358.txt',delim_whitespace=True)
In [291]: data
Out[291]: 
   userID  artistID    weight
0      45         7  0.711478
1     204       144  0.464000
2      36       650  2.423289
3     140       146  1.014670
4     170        31  1.412478
5     240       468  0.652999
In [292]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data.weight, (data.userID, data.artistID)))
In [293]: M
Out[293]: 
<241x651 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [294]: print(M)
  (36, 650)     2.42328874902
  (45, 7)       0.711477987421
  (140, 146)    1.01466992665
  (170, 31)     1.41247833622
  (204, 144)    0.464
  (240, 468)    0.652999240699
```

I can also load that file with `genfromtxt`:

```
In [307]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack48133358.txt',dtype=None, names=True)
In [308]: data
Out[308]: 
array([( 45,   7,  0.71147799), (204, 144,  0.464     ),
       ( 36, 650,  2.42328875), (140, 146,  1.01466993),
       (170,  31,  1.41247834), (240, 468,  0.65299924)],
      dtype=[('userID', '<i4'), ('artistID', '<i4'), ('weight', '<f8')])
In [309]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data['weight'], (data['userID'], data['artistID
     ...: '])))
In [310]: M
Out[310]: 
<241x651 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! Is there a specific reason, why the numbers are rounded in the matrix (e.g., 0.46399999999999997 -> 0.464)?