# Pandas: Dataframe to Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I'm quite new at this topics. I'm currently developing a latent factor matrix factorization that will be training data for a Neural Network.

I have a csv table like this:

```
user_id song_id playcount
frank   SOBYHAJ12A6701BF1D  23
john    SODACBL12A8C13C273  1
john    SODXRTY12AB0180F3B  3
mary    SOFRQTD12A81C233C0  1
```

You could think this table as a description of a matrix. I want to build a matrix as:

```
rows=song_id, columns=user_id, value=playcount
```

I've loaded the data into a pandas dataframe:

```
triplets_training_set = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Now I want to build a sparse matrix with that data.

Another question:

**Do I need to vectorize the values? i.e. translate '*b80344d063b5ccb3212f76538f3d9e43d87dca9e*' to a integer user_id? (same
with song_id)**

I've read questions like this but I don't know how to approach the last question

---

The only solution I came up with, was to first make 2 dicts like:

```
{ frank: 1, john: 2, mary:3, ..}
{ SOBYHAJ12A6701BF1D:1 , SODACBL12A8C13C273:2. ..}
```

and then iterate over the dataframe *triplets_training_set* row by row, constructing the matrix. But this is a naive solution. There must be a better one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `my_df.as_matrix()` and can you tell me why do you wanna build a sparse matrix with categorical values? You know what a sparse matrix is right?

Comment: @francarranza Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133358/create-sparse-matrix-with-pandas-and-fill-it-with-values-from-one-column-of-dat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
df.pivot(*df.columns)
Out[648]: 
song_id  SOBYHAJ12A6701BF1D  SODACBL12A8C13C273  SODXRTY12AB0180F3B  \
user_id                                                               
frank                  23.0                 NaN                 NaN   
john                    NaN                 1.0                 3.0   
mary                    NaN                 NaN                 NaN   
song_id  SOFRQTD12A81C233C0  
user_id                      
frank                   NaN  
john                    NaN  
mary                    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to encode the `user_id` and `song_id` fields into integers. These could then be used as the indices for your matrix. From there I would use your matrix of choice from [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) to load the data. Something like the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from scipy import sparse as ss

le = LabelEncoder()
user_ids = le.fit_transform(df.user_id)
song_ids = le.fit_transform(df.song_id)

sarr = ss.csr_matrix((df.playcount, (user_ids, song_ids)))
sarr
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
sarr.todense()
matrix([[23,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  3,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  1]], dtype=int64)
```